# Datastax cassandra-driver (python) failed import

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

When importing datastax cassandra-driver(python) get the following error

Error

```
File "cassandra.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
File "/home/vagrant/cassandra.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ImportError: No module named cluster
```

This is the code

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
print dir(cassandra.cluster)
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('userspace')
rows = session.execute('SELECT user_name, gender FROM users')
for user_row in rows:
    print user_row.user_name, user_row.gender
```

Comment: Asking the obvious: did you `pip install cassandra-driver` first?

Comment: Ya did that also compiled from source

Comment: Run your python with ``-vv`` and execute ``from cassandra.cluster import Cluster``. You'll see where it tries to find the package. Make sure that the package is available at PYTHONPATH

Comment: It is listed in my python path also in pip

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, it looks like names conflict. Your script is `cassandra.py` and so it is the module for the driver. Try to rename your script (and don't forget to delete its `.pyc`) and try again

Comment: Any file which matches a keyword (say select.py) will make it run that file instead of resolving the keyword. I was using a script named - select.py which resulted in similar error and when I renamed the script to something which could not match any of it, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Install *CQL interactive terminal*:

```
sudo pip install cqlsh
```

Answer (score 0):

*I tried this and it worked in my case:*
python -m pip install  `

*for example:* python -m pip install cassandra-driver

Comment: that was another problem - that's why there is an accepted answer...

Comment: I have just given example he cas use it to install the package he want to install.

Comment: He had driver already installed via pip - see comment on the question